Gutenberg Dev - React Context.Provider returns undefined
I have a Context.Provider with a value setup in slider/edit.js.
When I import it in the child component slide/edit.js with useContext it returns undefined
I don't see what I'm missing here
For context here is the folder structure
src
    slider
        edit.js
        index.js
    slide
        edit.js
        index.js

build
    slider
        index.js
    slide
        index.js

index.js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
} );

slider/edit.js
import React, { createContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor'

export const SlideContext = createContext()

export default function Edit() {
    const slideRefs = useRef([])

    const setSlideRef = (ref, index) => {
        slideRefs.current[index] = ref
        console.log('setSlideRef called with ref:', ref, 'and index:', index)
    }

    // some code omitted for brevity

    console.log('Rendering Slider component with context value:', { setSlideRef })

    const blockProps = useBlockProps()

    return (
        <SlideContext.Provider value={{ setSlideRef }}>
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <div className='splash-slider__wrapper'>
                    <div
                        className='splash-slider__track'
                    >
                        <InnerBlocks
                            allowedBlocks={['splash-blocks/slide']}
                            renderAppender={() => <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender />}
                            templateLock={false}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </SlideContext.Provider>
    )
}


slide/edit.js
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor'
import { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from '@wordpress/element' // Same as React
import { SlideContext } from '../slider/edit' // Import the context from the parent block

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes, clientId }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'splash-slider__slide'
    })
    const slideRef = useRef()

    const slideContext = useContext(SlideContext)
    console.log('slideContext:', slideContext) // logs: undefined
    const { setSlideRef } = slideContext || {}

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('slideRef.current:', slideRef.current) // logs correctly
        if (setSlideRef && slideRef.current) {
            console.log('Setting slideRef with clientId:', clientId)

            setSlideRef(slideRef, clientId)
        }
    }, [setSlideRef, clientId])

    return (
        <div {...blockProps} ref={slideRef}>
            // InspectorControls and PanelBody omitted for brevity
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    )
}



have you declared in the block registration that it provides context and then declared in the child block that it consumes context? I see the name from the block.json is being passed into the block registration but nothing else, and it's unclear what block.json contains or if both blocks use the same index.js code. If you don't declare explicitly what context is used it'll be filtered out by the block editor before it reaches your block both in JS and on the server when rendering

@TomJNowell I have not provided context in block.json. I will take a look into that. The code of index.js is the same for both blocks in slider/index.js and slide/index.js.
